# How to load image from URL on watchos 2?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

Is there any framework can be used to load an image from URL in watchos 2 ? I tried SDWebImage but it doesn't support watchos2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its no framwork, but I've written this extension:

```
extension WKInterfaceImage {
    public func imageFromUrl(_ urlString: String) {

        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {

            let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as URL)
            let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
                if let imageData = data as Data? {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.setImageData(imageData)
                    }
                }
            });

            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

Just add a WKInterfaceImage to your watchOS storyboard, attach it and then call 
`imageView.imageFromUrl("https://something")`

Let me know if it works!